# Is Wolfram Mathematica compatible with all the operating system images?

Tags: software-installation, operating-systems

I read that Raspberry PI comes with a license of Wolfram Mathematica but it is not so clear if it is possible to use it with all the system images or only with the default one.

It seems that it is just a matter of running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wolfram-engine` as it is stated [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/the-wolfram-language-and-mathematica-on-raspberry-pi-for-free/) but I'd like to have a confirmation from someone that is using it with a system other than raspian or the NOOBs packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on raspbian wolfram is included in the default repository:

```
$ apt-cache search wolfram
wolfram-engine - Mathematica® and the Wolfram Language
```

other systems most likely lack in this department, and you'll need to download, unpack, install (maybe compile) things manually.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know for sure, I think the only two compatible OSes are Arch and Raspbian, as RaspBMC, OpenELEC and RISCOS are not 'flexible' enough for software like Mathematica.

Comment: Is it included in Arch default repository?

Comment: Unfortunately not. wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mathematica